# Ghost - Send invitation to user outside admin panel

Tags: ghost-blog, ghost

I would like to make a `HTML` form to invite users to be authors in a blog. I know that the logic is located in the ghost source at `"ghost/core/built/assets/ghost.js"` and it defines a modal `'ghost/controllers/modals/invite-new-user'` but how can I use this from the outside?

In the API reference there is no resource for create an user. Is this possible without the API?